# f a continuous function satisfying $\sqrt{xy}(f(x) + f(y)) \leq 1 \; \forall x,y \in [0\; 1]$ Show that $\int_0^1 f(t) dt \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f :[0 \; 1] \rightarrow R $ be  a continuous function satisfying

$ \sqrt{xy}(f(x) + f(y)) \leq 1  \; \forall x,y \in [0\; 1]$    ....(1) 
Show that 
$\int_0^1 f(t) dt \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $
.... (2)

Is there any continuous function satisfying the inequality (1) and achiveing the equality (2)

Comment: Where did this problem arise?

Comment: Then I don't think MathOverflow is an appropriate place for other people to be helping students with assignments

Comment: The point of challenges is for **you** to attempt them, and then to ask the person who posed the challenge when **you** get stuck. Otherwise, they would not be challenges. The reward is in the attempt, not in being able to find someone else's answer.

Comment: This site is for research level questions. For general questions in mathematics see http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

In the inequality $\sqrt{xy}(f(x)+f(y))\leq 1$ set $y=1-x$. Then
$$f(x)+f(1-x)\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}.$$

Integrate from $0$ to $1$ and obtain
$$2\int_0^1f(x)dx\leq\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=\pi.$$
So
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx\leq\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Since it is known that this is a [challenge problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444203/f-a-continuous-function-satisfying-sqrtxyfx-fy-leq-1-forall-x-y#comment1146700_444203), and that the user is [not interested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444203/f-a-continuous-function-satisfying-sqrtxyfx-fy-leq-1-forall-x-y#comment1146709_444203), I think the question should not be answered here.

Comment: @LSpice: I do not really care about the circumstances that you mention. Do you know what is the best possible estimate, and an extremal function?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Thanks for the correction.